# How can I call the same instance of a class from one method to another?

Tags: c#, wpf

- Every time the button is clicked, a window instance of DataDisplay
  gets created
- Each window has different data to be displayed
- Calling each window instance to method dispatcherTimer_Tick for
  refreshing the data every 5 sec.

NOTE: I don't wanna declare DataDisplay globally as I need multiple window instances every time I click the button.

Code Sample:

```
private void applyBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         ..

         DataDisplay dd = new DataDisplay();

        //This will create multiple instances of the DataDisplay screen with individual query

         ..

}

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   ..

   dd.dataGrid.Items.Refresh();

    //Refresh data for each instance of DataDiaplay
    ..

}
```

Comment: Are you asking how the `dispatcherTimer_Tick` method can invoke a method on each of the `DataDisplay` instances to tell them that they should refresh their values?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it a class-level field, outside of any of the methods, that holds a collection of your objects e.g.:

```
private List<DataDisplay> allDisplayData = new List<DataDisplay>();

private void applyBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    allDisplayData.Add(new DataDisplay());
}

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    foreach (var dd in allDisplayData)
    {        
        dd.dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: Declaring private DataDisplay dd = new DataDisplay(); globally won't let me create multiple instances when the button is clicked.

Comment: You still need to do it globally in order to access it in another method.  You can just hold a collection of them instead of a single one.  See my update.

Comment: As you iterate through the list, you probably want to confirm that the `DataDisplay` instance is still open before attempting to refresh its grid. If it's no longer open, you probably also want to remove it from the list. You probably also want to synchronize access to the list since `applyBtn` could be clicked (and the list therefore modified) while iterating through it.

Comment: @wablab -- That's superfluous information as far as this question and my answer goes.  Post that comment under the OP's question if you want, but it's not relevant here.

Comment: @roryap, the synchronization aspect certainly isn't superfluous. You risk exceptions otherwise.

Comment: @wablab: I would agree that this is not a very good answer (but given how poor the question is, perhaps it's the best one might expect). That said, your concerns about synchronization issues are unfounded. `DispatcherTimer` raises the `Tick` event in the UI thread. It is not possible for a button click event to be handled while the `Tick` event handler is executing, as both will use the same thread.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, excellent point! I've obviously spent too long developing server components -- I didn't even realize there was such a thing as `DispatcherTimer`. I'm shocked that I've never come across it before, but thanks for bringing it to my attention!